# How to minimizing android app cache size

Tags: android, caching, launching

my android app cache size is around 40MB when i load the app into device and it is showing blank screen while launching the app for 1st time. i have no idea how to resolve this challenge, please help.

these are the libraries i am using.

```
compile(group: 'com.microsoft.azure', name: 'azure-notifications-handler', version: '1.0.1', ext: 'jar')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.microsoft.azure.android:azure-storage-android:0.6.0@aar'
compile 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-mobile-services-android-sdk:2.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need some sort of splash screen to entertain user while app is loading. But there's a catch... as app is still being loaded how can it run any code to show a splash screen? In fact it can't really, but luckily there's a solution: during the loading time, the window manager draws a placeholder UI for your app, using elements from your theme, such as the background and status bar color. Setting the theme properly allows you to i.e. show static image (no code is loaded yet, so no fancy animation at that point) instantly. The key is to create custom theme that overrides `android:windowBackground` attribute, and once your app is loaded and starts running, you just replace that theme with your standard one, before calling `super.onCreate()` in your Activity.

Here's Google+ post of Ian Lake that describes this technique in details: [Use cold start time effectively with a branded launch theme](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/Z1Wwainpjhd).

Comment: Thanks for the reply  @Marcin Orlowski , i will try that.. is there away to reduce app cache memory consumption...

Comment: Try using ProGuard to strip unused portions of included libraries (it's called "minifing" in project settings). Also check this:http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-shrinking

Comment: thanks a lot, it worked wonderfully. i am so amazed by my app response while loading, 30 sec to less than 2 sec :)  unfortunately don't have enough reputations to up-vote.. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would try [this guide](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/) You probably cant put an animation there, but showing some resource rather than the black/white screen when your app loads up first time sounds good.

Comment: Thanks a lot @parohy :) helped me to give better UX on cold firing of the app.. unfortunately don't have enough reputations to up-vote... thanks again